Why flush a RandomAccessFile always failed?
I use "rw" mode and want to flush content into device:
RandomAccessFile random= new RandomAccessFile(path.toFile(), "rw");
random.write(1);

But they always failed on flush operation:
//Force failed
random.getChannel().force(true);

or
//sync failed
random.getFD().sync();

There is no detail reason:
sync failed
java.io.SyncFailedException: sync failed
    at java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(Native Method)

Other modes also produce the same error:"rwd","rws". Why and how to solve?
A similar question:  How do I flush a 'RandomAccessFile' (java)?.
In this question, somebody mentioned using the getFD().sync() method, which apparently seemed to work correctly for them. However, for me after testing, both getFD().sync() and getChannel().force(true) consistently throw errors (although the data can still be written to the device correctly). I want to know whether these methods are supposed to always fail or am I missed something.

This question is similar to: How do I flush a 'RandomAccessFile' (java)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What OS are you running on?  What kind of file are you using?  What kind of file system?  (There are various possible explanations, for what you are seeing ... but we need more information to narrow it down.)

For Linux some possible reasons for failure are: running out of disk space, competing writes on the same file from elsewhere.
